# How do I make a web page(with many scripts which require internet to load) available offline?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, web

I want to have a specific web page which usually connects to a server to load the page available offline.

More specifically, I want to make https://www.desmos.com/calculator available in chrome even when I'm not connected to the internet.

I know it should be possible because once I load it with access to the internet, I can keep it open in that tab and use it even when I'm offline. The problem is when I am already offline and I try to open it. From this, I concluded that the page uses only javascript to run without any further internet connections after it loads.

I've tried loading it from cache("Show cached copy") and also downloading the whole website, but nothing worked.

Is there something like an extension or even another browser or program which I can use to access this website while offline?

P.S. I am also willing to code my own extension if pointed in the right direction.

Comment: From a quick view of the code (ctrl-U) It seems that the essential part is in the css file linked from the line 21. It's under a path different from the page one but on the same site ( something like href="/assets/build/calculator_desktop-9d5dbd2e87a141f82286eb74aec5e69e32a6f640.min.css" ). Did you try to download it locally and modify the path inside the main file?

Comment: I tried downloading it locally with both "Save as..." and httrack with no luck. After reading your comment I decided to try the more "manual" way of using wget and matching the links to point to the correct local folder. And it worked! :D

Comment: Should I post this myself as an answer for people in the future to see?